# Vue Accordion with transition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to integrate the `Accordion` component with a body transition, but without success :( . All is working as well except the animation.

**template:**

```
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-title" @click="isOpen = !isOpen" :class="{'is-open': isOpen}">
      <span>{{title}}</span>
      <i class="ic ic-next"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body" :class="{'is-open': isOpen}">
      <div class="card">
        <slot name="body"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**component:**

```
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Title'
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }
```

**And styles:**

```
.accordion-body {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 0 16px;  
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1);  
  &:not(.is-open) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &.is-open {
    height: auto;
    // display: block;
    padding: 16px;
  }
}

.card {
  height: auto;
}
```

I tried to use `<transition>` but it doesn't work with `height` or `display` properties.
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` will remove your content and avoid the animation, you should trick with `opacity`, `overflow:hidden` and `height`, but you ll be forced to do a method for that.

For example (not tested, but inspiring):

**in template:**

```
<div class="accordion" @click="switchAccordion" :class="{'is-open': isOpen}">
  <div class="accordion-title">
    <span>{{title}}</span>
    <i class="ic ic-next"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**in component (add a method):**

```
  methods: {
    switchAccordion: function (event) {
      let el = event.target
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen // switch data isOpen
      if(this.isOpen) {
        let childEl1 = el.childNodes[1]
        el.style.height = childEl1.style.height
      } else {
        let childEl2 = el.childNodes[2]
        el.style.height = childE2.style.height // or .clientHeight + "px"
      }  
    }
  }
```

**in style:**

```
.accordion {
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1);
} 

.accordion-body {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 0 16px; 
  opacity:0
}

.is-open .accordion-body {
  opacity:0
}
```

In this case, your transition should work as you want.
The javascript will change the height value and transition `transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1);` will do the animation

Comment: JS does all the same as my CSS

Comment: I have no idea how to make slide-toggle animation on panel, I tricked with opacity, height, overflow and others for a few days

Comment: You have to change it with javascript in methods

Comment: i edited the post, you have to fit with your code, what i did it's not exact